# include a variable header path in C

Tags: c

I am trying to include a header file input by user at run time.

```
int main(){
char *p;
scanf("%s",p);
#include p
#define PATH path
#include PATH
}
```

Both the methods to include a header file are not working.Is there any way to include a header file input by user at run time?

Comment: Inclusions are resolved in pre-compilation, not at run time... you can't change the program after it's been compiled.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Are you sure you mean "include"? If you want to read that header/textfile and process it with your program instead, there are ways to do that. You will probably need to use `fopen()" and functions in the vicinity of "fscanf()". Search online for those terms and find a tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot include any header dynamically in C language because  `#include` being evaluated during compile time only(**Preprocessor directives** actually happens before compilation). You need to include the header statically with `#include <your_header_file.h>` or `#include "your_header_file.h"`.

Answer (score 1):

The header files are preprocessed in such a way that all the definitions are included into the file at compile time. In preprocessing all the `#include" "` or `#include< >` will be replaced by translator/ preprocessing unit of compiler.
If you will try to include them at runtime it will not make any sense. They are probable already removed.

Comment: sorry by mistake i wrote runtime. it is compile time(preprocessing stage).